# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

The question is this.

> In $h(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$, show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \ h(x) = \frac{1}{6}$, but that $h(0)$ is undefinied.

In my opinion if I use this expression $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$  above with the $-3$ inside the square root I got an undefinied expression, but if I put the $-3$ out of the square and I use this expression to calculate the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$ I will get $\frac{1}{6}$.

Here[image] a print screen of the original question.

If needed i can post the Pdf of the homework.

Comment: Multiply on top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+9}+3$ and re-evaluate.

Comment: In this case when I said put the -3 out, I just wanna to say that I´m redefining the function above.

Comment: The question was edited from the OP's original one.  I have edited it back.  @ViniciusL.Beserra please make sure this represents your intent.

Comment: The second function is a completely different function from the first function. Recheck the problem statement to ensure you have stated the initial problem correctly, and didn't misunderstand. Perhaps there is a typo, because, yes, the limit of the stated problem is undefined. that's not the case with the alteration.

Comment: 1-you can not take $-3$ outside the squareroot as you wish $2$- The limit of the original expression is defintely not $1/6$.

Comment: As a calculus teacher familiar with what kinds of exercises like this are out there, this is certainly a typo. The problem would have been intended to be about $\frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$.

Comment: Thanks folks. But the original question proposed by the teacher is that one commented by Alex.Jordan.

Comment: Yes, Vinicius: I see your posted image. I hope the fact that it's a typo/misprint reassures you, and/or the work in the answers confirms your work. Notify the teacher, and/or if no time to do so in advance, just hand in your work on both versions, the typo and what was no doubt intended. But just be clear that showing $h(0)$ is undefined applies to both the typo and the "intended" question. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

As I stated in the comments above, and as demonstrated by anorton:

$$h(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x + 9} - 3}{x} \neq \frac{\sqrt{x+ 9 - 3}}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x+6}}{x}$$

So ... Assuming the problem statement (from the original source) *actually* reads:

> In $h(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}$, show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \ h(x) = \frac{1}{6}$, but that $h(0)$ is undefined.

- We can take the $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)\;$ by applying L'Hopital's Rule because, as is, the limit evaluates to the *indeterminate* form $\frac 00$.
- If you're not familiar with L'Hopital, then you can multiply the numerator and denominator by the *conjugate* of the numerator: the conjugate of $\sqrt{x + 9} - 3$ is simply $\sqrt{x + 9} + 3.\;$ *Then* simplify and evaluate the limit of the resulting expression. (See $(1)$ below.)

Either route taken will give you an expression for which the limit can be evaluated. And as you note: $$\lim_{x\to 0} h(x) = \dfrac 16$$

**Now, why is $h(0)$ undefined? Because division by zero is undefined. Period.**

But to say that the *function* is undefined when evaluated at $0$, i.e., that $h(0)$ is undefined *is **not** to say* that $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$ is undefined. Limits often exist at points for which a function is not defined. After all, the limit as $x \to a$ of $f(x)$ gives you the value *to which $f(x)$ approaches* as $x \to a$ , irregardless of whether the function is undefined AT $x = a$.

---

$(1)$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x + 9}-3}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x + 9} - 3}{x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x + 9} + 3}{\sqrt{x + 9} + 3}$$ 
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x + 9 - 9}{x(\sqrt{x + 9} + 3)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x\left(\sqrt{x + 9} + 3\right)} $$ 
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ x + 9} + 3}= \frac{1}{6}$$

---

ADDED: There is clearly a typo in the original pdf of the question (the image of which you have now posted.) That is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+9 - 3}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x + 6}}{x} \to \frac{\sqrt{6}}{0}, \text{ so that} \lim_{x\to 0} h(x)\to\infty.$$

So I suspect that was intended for this problem (without the misprint) is the function highlighted above, whose limit, as you observe, is then $1/6$. In either case, though, $h(0)$ is undefined, because we cannot divide by zero.

Answer (score 6):

To show something slightly different than the other answers:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x + 9}-3}{x} &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x + 9}-3}{x}\frac{\sqrt{x + 9}+3}{\sqrt{x + 9}+3} \\&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+9-9}{x(\sqrt{x + 9}+3)} \\&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+9}+3} \\ &= \frac{1}{6}.
\end{align}
$$
Clearly the function isn't defined at $0$ because then you are dividing by $0$.

Comment: There is an $x$ missing after the $3$ in the second row. But this way might be easier if one is not familiar with the rule of L'Hospital.

Comment: I think the braces in the second row were not there when I said the $x$ was missing. Now it's okay.

Comment: Why is the first expression discontinuous at $x=0$, but the last expression is continuous at $x=0$ (despite the fact that they're algebraically equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pull the negative 3 out of the square root.  For example:
$$\sqrt{1-3} = \sqrt{2}i \ne \sqrt{1} - 3 = -2$$

Answer (score 2):

Of course $h(0)$ is undefined as you cannot divide by zero. As you said $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}x=\frac 1 6$, according to L'Hospital's rule. Why do you care about $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x+9-3}}x\ne h(x)$?

Comment: Yes. Clearly the original problem from the text had the $-3$ *not* under the radical sign. The OP mistook that "placing it in or out" as the "reason" $h(0)$ is undefined (missing the point of zero division). +1

Answer (score 0):

1. Way to solve this:
   $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}*\frac{\sqrt{x+9}+3}{\sqrt{x+9}+3})=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x}{x*(\sqrt{x+9}+3)})=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+9}+3})=\frac{1}{6}$$
2. Way to solve this:
   Use L'Hospital rule:
   $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\sqrt{x+9}-3)'}{x'}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2*\sqrt{x+9}}}{1}=\frac{1}{6}$$