# Evaluate the limit of following

Tags: limits

I need help in evaluating the limit of this expression.
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}x$$

Comment: Try multiplying the top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+4}+2$.

Comment: Maybe it will help you if you have a look how some similar limits have been solved: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345251/evaluating-lim-x-to-0-frac-sqrtx9-3x and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627321/how-can-i-find-the-following-limit-lim-limits-x-to-4-frac-sqrtx5-3x

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing other than the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ evaluated at 4:

Define $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.  Note that $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Then $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{4+x}-\sqrt4}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(4+x)-f(4)}{x} = f'(4) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{4}} = \dfrac{1}{4},$$

where the third equality is justified by the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{x}
=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(\sqrt{x+4}-2)(\sqrt{x+4}+2)}{x(\sqrt{x+4}+2)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x+4-4}{x(\sqrt{x+4}+2)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x}{x(\sqrt{x+4}+2)}
=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}+2}
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt4+2}
=\dfrac{1}{2+2}
=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

it is
$\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-2}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}+2}$
thus the searched limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.
Sonnhard.